# i am facing error in my c++ codes warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

Tags: c++

here is the codes In this little assignment you are given a string of space separated numbers, and have to return the highest and lowest number

```
#include <string>

std::string highAndLow(const std::string& numbers)
{
    int big,small;
    int a;
    a = numbers.length();
    big = numbers[0];
    small = numbers[0];
    for(int i=0;i<a; i++)
    {
        if(big<numbers[i+1])
            big = numbers[i+1]; 

    }
    for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        if(small > numbers[i+1])
            small = numbers[i+1];


    }
    std::cout<<big<<" "<<small;
}
```

Comment: The error itself is clear enough. The function states it returns a string, yet you don't return one

Comment: Either make the function `void` or make it `return` a `std::string`

Comment: change `std::cout<<big<<" "<<small;` to `return std::to_string(big) + " " + std::to_string(small);`

Comment: I can't type "control reaches..." before google finishes the sentence and points to exactly why you are having this issue. Don't be afraid to do a word for word search of the compiler error.

Answer (score 1):

Your function has a return type of `std::string`, so the compiler will require that you return one. In the case that you have some sort of branching (e.g. if-else statements), then it must also be the case that you return one by the end of each branch. If any of the above is violated, you will receive this error message. In this case, you can either change your function to be a void function (and then having no return is completely acceptable) or you can update it to return a `std::string`.